# ios simulator proxy settings

Tags: ios, proxy, settings, simulator

I'm writing a code to use the google api's, so through the application I can search for some words through google api, unfortunately, the ios proxy simulator always prevents me from accomplishing that tasks because of the following error:

> credentials could not be authenticated

When I'm using the safari on the mac I can access the internet, and when I'm using safari on the ios simulator itself, I can access the internet also, but I can't access from the code itself.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what iOS Proxy Simulator is?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to utilize proxy servers requiring authentication with the iOS Simulator.